# sudo askpass: ask from other tty

Tags: sudo, rsync, tty, expect

## Context

I want to setup `rsync` backups of my server, so I run the following command

```
rsync -r -e ssh --rsync-path="sudo rsync" rsyncuser@example.com:/ /backup/
```

Ideally, that command would ask my private ssh key password, then connect, then ask the sudo password for rsyncuser, and then run rsync on the server. But I got the infamous error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

So I had to add this to `/etc/sudoers` (using `sudo visudo`), which basically gives passwordless full read-write access to the system to the user `rsyncuser`, which is not to my taste:

```
rsyncuser ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

## Question

**How can I instead tell sudo to read its password from, say, another TTY ?**

That way, I could run `rsync` in one terminal window on my local machine, and use another terminal window to open a (possibly separate) ssh connexion to the server, and supply the sudo password there.

The only way I think of doing something like that would be to use an `expect` script around sudo, which reads the password from a named pipe, and I would write to that pipe from the other terminal.

Note: this is more for the sake of exeprimentation and learning than any practical purpose, *I'm not trying to find out how to use sudo with rsync*, I've already read all I could find about that.

Comment: Have you tried `rsync -e 'ssh -t' ...`?

Comment: @peterph I just tried that, I get `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Answer (score 6):

`sudo` will read an environment variable, `SUDO_ASKPASS`, if it is not running from a terminal (as in your case) or if -A is set. It uses this as a command to run to get the password. For example:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nhead -n 1' > ~/bin/reader
chmod a+x ~/bin/reader
export SUDO_ASKPASS="$HOME/bin/reader"
sudo -A echo "I'm root\!"
```

Will prompt you for the password on stdin, and won't require a terminal.

In the specific case of what you are trying to do however, it might be better to allow root SSH login, but only with an SSH key and the command restricted to rsync. There is a good resource on this [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/paranoid-penguin-managing-ssh-scripts-and-cron-jobs?page=0,1).

Comment: How does that work? `reader` just runs `head` with no input. On my debian (bash), it expects the root password but I don't get the prompt. Presumably because `-A` suppresses it. The net result is my root password written visibly in my terminal before the command executes.

Comment: @terdon I intended `reader` only as an example to show how SUDO_ASKPASS works. No one should actually use a script like that. And yes, it suppresses the usual `sudo` prompt, allowing `head` to read it from the terminal, perfectly visible.

Comment: Nice then, +1 :)

Comment: I +1'd at no one should actually use a script like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ssh userfoo@host "sudo -S p'enter pw: ' [command] "
```

This will issue a password prompt ("`enter pw:`") that will display on your local host/terminal.  The downside of this is the security risk from your password being displayed in the clear on your terminal window.  It will not be saved in your local `.bash_history`, but it is the terminal window scroll-back history.  So, if you're using Konsole for example, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to clear that.